# Sharing customTags.tld between projects

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, jstl, tld

I have created two projects 'webutils' and 'website'

In website I have created custom tag library and customTags.tld file for tag reference.

In my jsp's i am using this

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tags/customTags.tld"  prefix="tt"%>
```

It works fine. and i am able to use

```
<tt:mytag/>
```

NOW problem is i want to move my tag library into webutils project. Moving only java package with java-files works, but i want to move customTags.tld file to webutils too. When i do that it does not work. I cannot refer .tld files.

let me know if more clarification on problem is required, as I am assuming lots of things.

I am using gradle & spring-boot.

Forgot to mention few things, 'website'  depends on 'webutils'. And I am using gradle.

Answer (score 2):

> If you want to redistribute your tag files or implement your custom
>   tags with tag handlers written in Java, you must declare the tags in a
>   tag library descriptor (TLD). A tag library descriptor is an XML
>   document that contains information about a library as a whole and
>   about each tag contained in the library. TLDs are used by a web
>   container to validate the tags and by JSP page development tools.
>
> Tag library descriptor file names must have the extension .tld and
>   must be packaged in the /WEB-INF/ directory or subdirectory of the WAR
>   file **or in the /META-INF/ directory or subdirectory of a tag library
>   packaged in a JAR**. If a tag is implemented as a tag file and is
>   packaged in /WEB-INF/tags/ or a subdirectory, a TLD will be generated
>   automatically by the web container, though you can provide one if you
>   wish.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags6.html

So, if using Maven, for example, place the .tld under

src/main/resources/META-INF

Comment: how do i refer this .tld  in my jsp?

Comment: You specify an uri in your tld and then reference it as you would any other taglib . See previous link.

Comment: it works if tld is in same project, but not if it is in another project, say it is working if i pur it in 'website' but not when i put it in 'webutils'. I want to refer .tld from jsp's in website project.